# Use data-disabled-with on a non form submit button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button, ujs, disable-link

Rails provides data-disabled-with for button tags on form submits. Super awesome. However, link tags don't get this desired behavior. They're great to prevent users from clicking a button too many times and producing an unwarranted effect.

Is there a way I can do something like:

```
<a href="www.somewhere.com" data-disabled-with="Please Wait">Purchase me</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails provides this functionality via the :disable_with parameter of the link_to helper. [See docs](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to).

For example:

```
link_to("Create", create_post_path(@post), remote: true, disable_with: "Creating...")
```

Recognizing of course that creating a resource via a GET request isn't idiomatic Rails/REST... but this hopefully illustrates how it could be used.